# Existence of sequence of test functions converging to a constant

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, distribution-theory

I read somewhere that it is possible to find a sequence of test functions $\phi_{\epsilon} \in C^{\infty}_{c}(0,1)$ such that

- $\phi_{\epsilon} \ge 0$,
- $\phi_{\epsilon} \to 1$ as $\epsilon \to 0$,
- $\|\phi_{\epsilon}'\|_{L^{2}(0,1)} \lesssim  1 $ .

I wish to know if this claim is actually true or not.
I am doubting this mainly because of the final statement which says that the derivatives are uniformly bounded. The reason I doubt this is because if this sequence is converging to $1$ and each element has compact support then surely the derivatives would have to be 'really large' near the endpoints $x=0$ and $x=1$? Intuitively I don't see how you could cook up a sequence of functions which have compact support, converge to $1$ AND have derivative uniformly bounded in $L^{2}$.

Comment: By your P.S. do you mean that the inequality should be $\lesssim$ (which is \lesssim in tex)? If so, this means that there exists a constant $C$ such that $\|\phi_\epsilon'\|_{L^2(0,1)} \le C$.

Comment: @RhysSteele Yes exactly, thank you for enlightening me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed this is false.  Suppose there exists a constant $C$ such that $\|\phi'_\epsilon\|\leq C$ for all $\epsilon$ (all norms in this answer are the $L^2$ norm).  Then for each $\delta>0$, $$|\phi_\epsilon(\delta)|=\left|\int_0^\delta\phi'_\epsilon\right|\leq\|\phi'_\epsilon\|\|1_{[0,\delta]}\|=C\sqrt{\delta}$$ by Cauchy-Schwarz.  For $\delta$ sufficiently small relative to $C$, this means $\phi_\epsilon(\delta)$ is always close to $0$, and so cannot converge to $1$ as $\epsilon\to 0$.

Comment: Thank you very much, I've accepted your answer. I couldn't help but notice that this argument fails if we instead required $\|\phi_{\epsilon}'\|_{L^{1}} \le C$. Do you think the statement would still be false with this new hypothesis?

Comment: @duelspace with the $L^2$ norm replaced by the $L^1$ norm the statement is true. Let $\psi$ be a smooth non-negative function such that $\psi(x) = 0$ for $x \in [0,1/4]$ and $\psi(x) = 1$ for $x \in [3/4,1]$. Define $\phi_\epsilon(x) = \psi(\epsilon^{-1}x)$ for $x \in (0, \varepsilon]$, $\phi_\epsilon(x) = 1$ for $x \in [\epsilon, 1-\epsilon]$ and suppose that $\phi_\epsilon(x) = \phi_\epsilon(1-x)$ for all $x \in (0,1)$. Then 
$\|\phi_\epsilon'\|_{L^1(0,1)} = 2 \| \varepsilon^{-1} \psi'(\varepsilon^{-1} \cdot) \|_{L^1(0, \varepsilon)} \lesssim \|\psi'\|_{L^\infty}$.

Comment: @RhysSteele I see, so the $L^{1}$ norm is the only one which cancels this factor of $1/\epsilon$ appearing in front of the mollifier. Thanks!